# Save As Dialog Box freezes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, savefiledialog

I have a winform Application and there is a code to open `Save as Dialog box`.

```
DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

The program very well runs on Windows XP but on Win 7 the application hangs, the debugger does not return from this line of code. The `Event Viewer` detail reads as follows

`The Program Sample.exe stopped interacting with windows and was closed`

Has anyone been through this problem?

**Update**

It seems that the error was caused due to the code running on another thread which I have nowremoved .Although it is not recommended to access UI elements from another thread I am surprised why I didnt get this error while running on XP ??

Comment: after googling the error, it just seems to be an explorer.exe issue, does this sound plausible?
how many Windows 7 machines have you tried?

Comment: `Build` -> `Rebuild Solution`?

Comment: @SecretSquirrel I tried creating Sample project with only one form and Button and onbutton click I am trying to open Save as Dialog box...but the window just freezes

Comment: Not sure if this could cause your particular problem, but any time there's a weird problem with the common dialogs, it's worth making sure that your app is running in an STA thread. Does your app's entry point (typically `Program.Main()`) have the `[STAThread]` attribute? Are you showing any UI from threads other than the default thread?

Comment: @Kyle As other people are saying this sort of error occurs when there are corrupt files on disk, etc. 
But I cannot see this being the problem unless all 5 machines are corrupt. 
I am sorry but to be honest I cannot help anymore with this.

Comment: Also, is there anything in common between the Windows 7 machines you've tested on? This could easily be caused by a badly-behaved shell extension -- and normally five different machines wouldn't all have the same badly-behaved shell extension, but if it's a corporate network, the chances go way up.

Comment: @JoeWhite I created new instance of Visual studio added  form and a button on it..On button click surprisingly the `save As dialog box` is working but not on my main project

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the [`InitialDirectory` property of the dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx)?

If you are, try setting it to another location if you are not you could try setting it.

If this is defaulting to a network path, it could be taking the time opening that path?

Answer (score 1):

This could be result of corrupted file system or hard disk. When save dialog is invoked, it will try to get the list of hard drives , logical drives and folders. If any of it is corrupt, it will hang/throw an exception.

Try running same app in different Windows 7 machine

Answer (score 0):

Did you run System File Chccker (SFC) scan on the windows 7 which would scan for corrupt system files on the computer and replace them.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833